# JS create new array from certain item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 dimensional array `myArray`:

```
[
  [ '567576', 'John', 'Doe' ],
  [ '098897', 'John', 'Doe' ],
  [ '543539', 'John', 'Doe' ],
  [ '234235', 'John', 'Doe' ],
  [ '345348', 'John', 'Doe' ],
  [ '432574', 'John', 'Doe' ]
]
```

Is it possible to create a new array from `myArray` starting from a certain first value?
For example create a new array starting from id `543539`. Anything above the array containing `543539` will not be added.

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: SO isn't a coding service; what have you attempted here? I'd look into `Array.map()` and `Array.filter()`.

Comment: In fact, almost everything imaginable is possible in js :D

Comment: NewArray = myArray.slice(myArra.findIndex((el)=>el[0]==543539))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `findIndex()` which returns the index of the first item that matches the condition.
Combine it with `slice()` to cut your array at the specific position:

```js
const myArray = [
  ['567576', 'John', 'Doe'],
  ['098897', 'John', 'Doe'],
  ['543539', 'John', 'Doe'],
  ['234235', 'John', 'Doe'],
  ['345348', 'John', 'Doe'],
  ['432574', 'John', 'Doe']
]

console.log(myArray.slice(myArray.findIndex(item => item[0] === "543539")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming all the internal arrays are structured the same way, you can do something like `let newArray = myArray.filter(innerArray => Number(innerArray[0]) > 543539)`

Edit: This is assuming you want all subarrays where the first item is a number larger than 54539, as opposed to finding all of the subarrays that physically follow the first occurrence of a subarray with 54539 as the first value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible and straightforward process.
You can use the javascript map method which returns a new array

```
newArray = myArray.map(item=> item[0])
```